# Comparing Vectors Values: 1 element with all other

Tags: r, vector, compare

I'm wondering how I can compare 1 element of a vector with all elements in the other vector. As an example: suppose

```
x <- c(1:10)  
y <- c(10,11,12,13,14,1,7)
```

Now I can compare the elements parewise

```
x == y
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But I want to compare all elements of y with a specific element of x, something like

```
x[7] == y
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Is this possible?

Comment: do you want `%in%`? `x %in% y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(10,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
res <- outer(x, y, `==`)
colnames(res) <- paste0("y=", y)
rownames(res) <- paste0("x=", x)
```

Which gives you the following matrix:

```
      y=10   y=7  y=11  y=12  y=13  y=14  y=15  y=16  y=17  y=18
x=1  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=3  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=4  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=5  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=7  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=9  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x=10  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want the dimnames to be as `y[1]` use

```
colnames(res) <- paste0("y[", seq_along(y), "]")
rownames(res) <- paste0("x[", seq_along(x), "]")
```

which gives you:

```
       y[1]  y[2]  y[3]  y[4]  y[5]  y[6]  y[7]  y[8]  y[9] y[10]
x[1]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[2]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[3]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[4]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[5]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[6]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[7]  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[8]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[9]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[10]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

To get the index use `which` as follows:

```
which(res) 
[1] 10 17
```

As `R` saves matrices rowwise this results in 10 and 17.
If you want the index in x and y component use:

```
which(res, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
x=10  10   1
x=7    7   2
```

Comment: Understood, but i am working more elements, like 200, how can i find the location of  all TRUE  values in vector y, for example, y[1] and y[2] are TRUE so i can extract then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare each element of x to y, usually one of the 'apply' functions will help.

As follows:

> x <- c(1:10)
>
> y <- c(10,11,12,13,14,1,7)
>
> sapply(x,function(z){z==y})

Column i in the output is result from x[i]==y.

Is this what you're looking for?